# Force default screen resolution for Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, pixel

I am trying to develop an app for iOS and Android, and am running into a screen resolution problem.

For our text sizes, we're using `px`. This means that a user changing the text size on the tablet won't affect the text size in the app (we're using css for the styling, so `dp` won't work).

However, on the Pixel C tablet, you can also change the effective screen resolution (there are 5 different resolutions you can change to). This changes the default `px` size, so the text sizes are all different and it's causing layout issues for the app (buttons/spacing are set by percentages, so it's causing overlap).

My question is: is there a way to force the tablet (or maybe just the Pixel C) to use whatever the default screen resolution is? I don't want to force to a specific value, because not all tablets have the same screen size/resolution. But each tablet *should* have a default resolution...

Might there be a solution in the manifest somewhere?

Info: developing the app using HTML/Javascript/CSS

Comment: your app probably runs in a chromium? Does chromium offer some utility?

Comment: "you can also change the effective screen resolution" -- are you referring to Settings > Display > Display Size?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to force the tablet (or maybe just the Pixel C) to use whatever the default screen resolution is?

No.

> But each tablet should have a default resolution

Your UI may break on the default resolution of any device, given your description. If you cannot handle a certain resolution on the Pixel C, you may not be able to handle that resolution on other hardware, whether that resolution is the the default for the hardware or not.

> we're using css for the styling, so dp won't work

If you are using `WebView`, a CSS `px` behaves like an Android `dp`. If you are not using `WebView`, I fail to see how you are using CSS, and even if you are, how using some CSS-to-Android-theme converter would prevent you from using `dp` units.

You can read more about Android 7.0's display size option in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#screen-zoom).

Comment: This answer helped. We ended up deciding that we would only support certain resolutions, and used `requiresSmallestWidthDp` in the manifest file...